# Exception on static variables

Tags: java, exception

```
class A {
    static int a = 1 / 0;
}
```

In this code when we load the class, it will throw an exception because of arithmetic exception. How can I catch that exception?

Comment: you're missing an `;` please indent correctly.

Comment: Use `try` and `catch`

Answer (score 0):

use this code.

```
static int a=0;
try{
   a = 1/0;
}catch(Exception e){
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You can use try catch only inside static,init blocks and methods.this is a class attribute

Answer (score 0):

using static block

```
public class A {
    private static int a;
    static {
        try {
            a = 1 / 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No now the question is changed.My question is if someone is declaring on class level only and initializing it there only then what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Make it in static block.

```
static {
    try {
        Integer a = 1 / 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
  }
```